# webViewDidFinishLoad not firing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that I want to make visible after a link is loaded. It is hidden and everything works until it needs to be shown. I am positive I can make the UIWebView visible again because I have placed it after I called the URL. I am positive that the `webViewDidFinishLoading` method is not being called when the UIWebView is indeed finished loading, nor will it log what is in that method as well.  What could be causing this problem? Thanks. Here is my code:

The **.m** file:

```
@interface KnoxGradesViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
IBOutlet UIButton *log;
IBOutlet UISwitch *rem;
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *stat;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *about;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *username;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *password;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *login;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *warning;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *log;

-(IBAction)showAbout;
-(IBAction)checkFields; 
-(IBAction)logOut;
```

The **.h** file:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)mwebView {
NSLog(@"Got here!");
[mwebView setHidden:false];
 }
```

Comment: have you set the delegate of the UIWebView to be your KnoxGradesViewController?

Comment: How may I go about doing that? I am sorry, Im fairly new to this. Thanks.

Comment: in interface builder, right click/control click the UIWebView and drag (mouse button still held down) to the View Controller (in the left panel) containing the UIWebView. it should pop up a list containing "delegate" - select that.

Comment: Still not triggering it.. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i think you are missing the delegate assignment as well.  What Mike explained is correct, you can right click the webview in the Objects Panel within interface builder and link the delegate to the File's Owner.

OR  you could try doing it through code

in your **viewDidLoad**  you could add

```
[webView setDelegate:self];
```